# SQLite - Android App

Tags: android, sqlite, reactjs, react-native

I am new to SQLite and am creating an android application that requires a database.
I would like to know if I download SQLite from https://sqlite.org/download.html in Precompiled Binaries for Android. I have already encountered several SQLite tutorials but none about how to download SQLite. What do I do? Thank you.

Comment: SQLite comes with the Android OS

Comment: or I recommend [realm.io](https://realm.io/)

Comment: You may need this [React Native Android wrapper for SQLite](https://github.com/jbrodriguez/react-native-android-sqlite). And that's all =) Learn how to use it from its readme page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite comes with the Android OS. You have an official API ([SQLiteDatabase](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html)) to access it in your application. But I recommend to use any library that will simplify your development process.

Look at this [React Native Android wrapper for SQLite](https://github.com/jbrodriguez/react-native-android-sqlite). That's probably all you need. =) Learn how to use it from its readme page.

Comment: error <- mReactRootView = new ReactRootView(this);

error <- mReactInstanceManager = ReactInstanceManager.builder()

error <- mReactRootView.startReactApplication(error <-mReactInstanceManager, "YourProject", null);

setContentView(error <- mReactRootView);

Comment: @JãoVitor if you want to ask another question please create a separate post. You may refer this one if you find this helpful.